# How does the kernel track which processes receive data from an interrupt?

Tags: io, operating-system, kernel

In a preemptive kernel (say Linux), say process A makes a call to `getc` on `stdin`, so it's blocked waiting for a character. I feel like I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the kernel knows then to wake process A at this point and deliver the data after it's received.

My understanding is then this process can be put into a suspended state while the scheduler schedules other processes/threads to run, or it gets preempted. When the keypress happens, through polling/interrupts depending on the implementation, the OS runs a device driver that decodes the key that was pressed. However it's possible (and likely) that my process A isn't currently running. At this point, I'm confused on how my process that was blocked waiting on I/O is now queued to run again, especially how it knows which process is waiting for what. It seems like the device drivers hold some form of a wait queue.

Similarly, and I'm not sure if this is exactly related to the above, but if my browser window, for example, is in focus, it seems to receive key presses but not other windows. Does every window/process have the ability to "listen" for keyboard events even if they're not in focus, but just don't for user experience sake?

So I'm curious how kernels (or how some) keep track of what processes are waiting on which events, and when those events come in, how it determines which processes to schedule to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *events* that processes wait on are abstract software events, such as *a particular queue is not empty*, rather than concrete hardware events, such as a interrupt 4635 occurring.

Some configuration ( perhaps guided by a hardware description like device tree ) identifies interrupt 4635 as being a signal from a given serial device with a given address.  The serial device driver configures itself so it can access the device registers of this serial port, and attaches its interrupt handler to the given interrupt identifier (4635).

Once configured, when an interrupt from the serial device is raised, the lowest level of the kernel invokes this serial device's interrupt handler.  In turn, when the handler sees a new character arriving, it places it in the input queue of that device.   As it enqueues the character, it may notice that some process(es) are waiting for that queue to be non-empty, and cause them to be run.

That approximately describes the situation using condition variables as the signalling mechanism between interrupts and processes, as was established in UNIX-y kernels 44 years ago.  Other approaches involve releasing a semaphore on each character in the queue; or replying with messages for each character.   There are many forms of synchronization that can be used.

Common to all such mechanisms, is that the caller chooses to suspend itself to wait for io to complete; and does so by associating its suspension with the instance of the object which it is expecting input from.

What happens next can vary; typically the waiting process, which is now running, reattempts to remove a character from the input queue.  It is possible some other process got to it first, in which case, it merely goes back to waiting for the queue to become non empty.

So, the OS doesn't explicitly route the character from the device to the application; a series of implicit and indirect steps does.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful. So does this mean that only one process can consume a given character, or is this mutual exclusion something that is implementation-dependent (i.e. a driver could deliver the same character to multiple processes waiting?)

Comment: There are many strategies for this, again implemented by layers of abstractions in various OSes.  The culmination of sessions and job control in UNIX-derived OSes answers this, in a way that it only takes months of effort to understand :)

Comment: In short, the driver delivers it to a queue.  The manager of the queue decides which 'session' should get it, and the process belonging to that session gets it.  So, yet another abstraction layer.  If you play around with a process which sets its stdin into raw mode, fork()s, then both parent and child read(2) from 0, and printf("%d: got %c\n", getpid(), c); you can see how it works first hand.